# @Output childEvent not initialized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am fairly new to the Angular world and working on angular 7, I am doing some examples where components share data within, The Parent to child part working fine but when i am trying to send any values from child to parent it's not working.

It shows me this error [image]

**app-component.html**

```
<div>{{show}}</div>

<app-communicating-components [Parent]="message" (childEvent)="getMessage($event)"></app-communicating-components>
```

**app-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularLesson2';

  public message = 'Hello my child, Parents here';
  public show: string;


  getMessage($event) {
    this.show = $event;
  }
}
```

**communicating-components.component.html**

```
<p>
  {{Parent}}
</p>
<button (click)="fireEvent()">Fire from child</button>
```

**communicating-components.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-communicating-components',
  templateUrl: './communicating-components.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./communicating-components.component.css']
})
export class CommunicatingComponentsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() Parent;
  @Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();


  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  fireEvent() {
    this.childEvent.emit('Hi, I am child');
    console.log("event fire" + this.childEvent);
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your import `import { EventEmitter } from 'events';` is not the one you should import here. Try changing the import to `import {  EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

**UPDATE**

Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e8vftd) showing that it works

Answer (score 6):

With Angular newer versions, like 8 you have to:

1. Import correctly Emitter as k.s. said:
   `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'`
2. Initialize the emitter for Output: 
   `@Output()
   emisor = new EventEmitter<type>();`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answer helped me on some legacy code that had without me noticing just:    @Output()    emisor: EventEmitter<type>;